# how to return multiple rows of a single column separated by a ',' or html break in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, select

the sql query :

```
SELECT coloumn1
FROM tablex
WHERE id=10
and state='COL'
```

lets assume the above query retuns the following

```
coloumn1
---------
abc
def
geh
ijk
```

i need the result to be like this

```
coloumn1
---------
abc, def, geh, ijk
```

OR

```
coloumn1
---------
abc<br/>def<br/>geh<br/>ijk
```

how can achive a result set like the above?
PLZ!help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
DECLARE @varr nvarchar(1000)

SELECT 
    @varr = COALESCE(@varr + ',', '') + column1
FROM 
    tablex
WHERE
     id=10 
     and state='COL' 

PRINT @varr
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
Select Top 1 
substring(
    (SELECT coloumn1 FROM tablex WHERE id=10 and state='COL' for XML PATH( '' )), 
    0,
    Len((SELECT coloumn1 FROM tablex WHERE id=10 and state='COL' for XML PATH( '' ))) - 2
)
```

from tablex

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @list varchar(100);

SELECT COALESCE( @list + ', ', '') + CAST(Column1 as varchar(3))
FROM tablex
WHERE id = 10
```

Doh Sachin Shanbhag beat me to it